# Give me some awesome Web2py Tip & Tricks which makes you more productive

Tags: python, workflow, web2py

I have been working with web2py following its official web2py book and got to learn too many things. But a book never teaches a productive workflow. I would like to know what workflow you people use to increase you productivity and understanding of the framework as a whole.

Ex:
 I often use Web2py interactive shell to play with database objects and understand how they work.

Comment: +1 for the web2py interactive shell.  It's especially good when used with the `-M` switch to auto-load the model files.

Comment: I found this posting, looking for how to work with Web2py interactively. The -M was the secret ingredient...

./web2py.py -M -S AppName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Komodo Edit for development and Google App Engine for hosting.

To better understand web2py have a look at the files in gluon/ - for example [tools.py](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/tools.py) is fairly straightforward.

Comment: how do you debug things when you are lost! Komodo edit is a awesome editor but sadly it is not an IDE and Komodo IDE is a commercial product. i use eclipse for debugging.

Comment: you don't have to use an IDE to be productive

Comment: @hoju, What does gluon mean